# How to create a notification system for 30 days interval

Tags: php

I want to create a notification for warranty expiry date. the notification should be appear on the panel before 15 days of expiry and it will last on panel after 15 days of expiry and then goes to archive.

my php code

```
<?php
$exp_date = strtotime('2017-05-01');
$notify_start_date = strtotime('-15 days',$exp_date );
$notify_end_date = strtotime('+15 days', $exp_date);
$now = new DateTime();
$now = $now->format('Y-m-d');
$now = strtotime($now);


echo 'expiry date--->'.date('Y-m-d',$exp_date).'<br>';
echo 'nofity start date--->'.date('Y-m-d',$notify_start_date).'<br>';
echo 'nofity end date--->'.date('Y-m-d',$notify_end_date).'<br>';
echo 'today--->'.date('Y-m-d',$now).'<br>';


if ( $exp_date > $notify_start_date  &&  $exp_date < $notify_end_date ) {
    if ($exp_date < $now) {
        echo "already expired";
    } 
    if ($exp_date == $now) {
        echo "will expire today";
    }
    if ($exp_date > $now) {
        echo "going to expire ";
    }
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

my code shows the notification beyond 15 days in both case before and after
if I give the date 2017-06-31 still show in the notification panel and showing all the expired date from the past

Comment: your code seems correct, but what exaclty do you need to achieve ? In the if/else condition, I just modified the echo according to the results -> [TEST](https://eval.in/775711) is that what you want ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I got it. my MySql query was wrong. I was just doing this 
`SELECT * FROM <table_name>`
 instead of   
`SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE WEXP_DATE <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND WEXP_DATE >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -15 DAY);`

Comment: it's all fine then :)